# How can I run samba?

Tags: server, windows, configuration, samba

I have server running Ubuntu 10.10. Never used samba before, as I never had windows machines, but now I need it.

So I did: `apt-get install samba smbfs smbclient`.

Packages are installed, but I have no idea how to configure it. All howtos I found on the net relate to /etc/samba/something.conf, where I don't even have /etc/samba directory.

The only config I found is /etc/default/samba, which contains (aside from comments) only:

```
RUN_MODE="daemons"
```

All I want is to be able to have access to some directories on the Ubuntu machine from Windows, nothing else.

Comment: If you have the IP of the windows machine, just type this in an explorer: `smb://x.x.x.x`

Comment: @depesz are you using(installing samba) on ubuntu server or ubuntu Desktop?

Comment: @Kaustubh P - not sure I understand. I have both windows and linux ips, but I need to connect from windows to linux samba, so I can see (from windows) some directories on Linux server.

Comment: @Achu: server. As 3rd word in description suggests :)

Comment: just one question is the package samba-common and Samba-common-bin installed as it is this package which contains the files you will need btw they are normally installed automatically when you install samba.

Comment: @Allan: yes. list of packages: libsamba-hostconfig0, libsamba-util0, libwbclient0, python-smbc, samba, samba-common, samba-common-bin, system-config-samba.

Comment: First remove system-config-samba as it is a gui then reinstall samba and samba common "apt-get install xyz --reinstall"

Comment: @Allan: thanks. afterwards I got file /etc/samba/smb.conf - i assume that's all I need.

Comment: and smbusers to setup access and your good to go :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the "samba" package should have also installed the "samba-common" package which contains the /etc/samba/smb.conf file.

A lot of things depend on samba-common (including, indirectly, GNOME) so you probably had it installed before you installed Samba. Perhaps this directory was deleted by accident at some point?

You should be able to create it again from scratch by reinstalling the samba-common package, or by simply creating it manually. The only file that really matters in that directory is smb.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about setting Samba up on a server but the steps listed [here](http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_147/article_548-samba-quick-setup-on-ubuntu-1004.htm) worked for me to allow two Ubuntu pc's to share files with Windows pc's on my network.

Comment: This doc *also* refers to /etc/samba directory/files which I do not have.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been dealt with at length in the ubuntu documentation.

- https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/internet/C/networking-shares.html

  - This link provides instructions on how to share folder graphically. i.e with a gnome gui. Using a right click as described above. It also details potential missing dependencies in order to enable right click sharing.
- Assuming you are using gnome with a default installation.
- Simply locate a folder in Nautilus or the file browser and

  - right click on the folder,
  - select properties
  - select the share tab
  - tick the share this folder box
  - Assign privileges necessary
  - tick allow guest access to enable people to browse the share on the network.
  - tick allow other to create and delete to allow users on the network to delete and create directories.
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide

  - This link contains a detailed discussion on command line use of samba, samba configuration with from /etc/samba/smb.conf.
  - Recommend this for advanced configuration and advanced users, or those having trouble sharing between windows.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with question. I already stated that there is no graphical environment, and the problem is not that I can't configure it, but that configuration file was altogether missing.

Answer (score -2):

Or you could simply use Webmin which is a web-based admin tool.